# Blank login page on CSWinPhone7SimpleApp

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the [Facebook C# SDK from Codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) on my WP7 app. I managed to build & run the application by manually adding Facebook.dll and Microsoft.Contracts.dll. But I only see a blank login(?) page :

[image]

The code enters `FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated`, after loading this url :

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=touch&scope=user_about_me,read_notifications&client_id=119779898114420&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

but the URL seems to have been redirected to this one :

`http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=119779898114420&cancel=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&fbconnect=1&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=permissions.request&app_id=119779898114420&display=touch&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html&response_type=token&fbconnect=1&perms=user_about_me%252Cread_notifications&from_login=1&rcount=1`

The important part is "User denied access", which I didn't, since I don't see anything except a blank page.

Thanks in advance !

edit: pasting the first url into an iPhone simulator Safari.app, I see the Facebook login screen, then after login, I see the grant permission screen...

Comment: I have updated the code of Facebook C# SDK wp7 sample, could you try downloading the latest source code and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

your browser is not script enabled, try to set the flag at true :